# What is it called when your boss pretend to ask you to do a task?

Tags: questions

For example, they ask:

> Would you like to do x?

When actually they want you to do x.

Or ask you:

> Do you agree with this?

and expect you to obey

Comment: So the question is about asking for something to be done rather than ordering something to be done?

Comment: @KillingTime like pretending to ask for consent

Comment: I think actual real-world examples would help here.

Comment: People sometimes say "I **was volunteered** to do [this task]" (rather than "I volunteered to do it").

Comment: It's called ***politeness***. Technically speaking, maybe ***circumlocution***.

Comment: Do you find the move cheeky or charming?

Comment: A polite/hedged instruction, but this isn't a defined term, so not justifying an 'answer'.

Comment: The context is completely unclear, so I vote to close.

Comment: That's not 'called' anything, unless it be either polite, or sneaky.

Answer (score 1):

Asking someone to do something you could otherwise demand they do, is a standard way of telling someone to do something.  As FumbleFingers suggests in his comment, we call this **politeness**. It's a cultural thing.

You can demand much more from a person when you state your demand as question.  When stating a demand as a question you also leave the door open for a response of *No I can't do that.  I have an appointment tomorrow.* So not only is it polite from a cultural standpoint, it is polite from a practical standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could express this using *scare quotes* (see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes)). For instance:

> My boss "asked" me if I "wanted" to do X.

Answer (score 0):

As Kate said, being volunteered works well here, although informally, some use  being voluntold to emphasize the fact that it's mandatory.